# How to highlight matching text in Excel column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a column in Excel in which random text entries are made. Like 'MSK', 'RK', 'LS' etc. One of the words from these entries is matching with entries in other cells like 'Chem(RK)', Math(MSK), Phy(LS). Is it possible to highlight cells containing one similar word? Like 'MSK' is also there in entry 'Math(MSK)'.

**Edit:** It doesn't matter in which the color cells will be highlighted, I only need to ensure the repetition of at least one word that is exactly (not partial) matching with the word in other cells. For example, my problem will be solved if the cells containing MSK, Math(MSK) and RK, Chem(RK) all get highlighted.

```
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
| MSK       |
| RK        |
| BK        |
| LS        |
| JS        |
| SM        |
| SnS       |
| EVS(SnS)  |
| Phy(LS)   |
| Chem(RS)  |
| Math(MSK) |
+-----------+
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? MSK is in the first cell, highlight that and all other cells containing it? Or do you want to highlight with different colours everything which have a match (like e.g. green for MSK, red for RK ...; if yes, this going to be very complicated)? Do you want to look for partial matches (e.g. should MSK match "MSK1" and "Math (MSK1)") or just one the exact word is found in brackets? Please edit your question to clarify these, and also include a screenshot with desired result.

Comment: The question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list is in `B6:B16`
and using an extra column + conditional formatting:

select `B6:B16` and set the color you like
in conditional formatting dialog and 
set `Formula` to `=C6`.

[image]

Then type in an **array formula** (
type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=MAX(2-ISERR(FIND("("&B6&")",$B$6:$B$16))-ISERR(FIND("("&$B$6:$B$16&")",B6)))
```

into `C6` and drag/copy it down to `C16`. This is the result:

[image]